# tensorflow: modify the shape of placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I meet this problem during my coding. I have a placeholder

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,128])
```

I want to generate some noise with dimension 10 and concatenate with x. The number of noises should match the number of xs that shows as None here and will be provided later. In numpy I would do it as:

```
noise_shape=[x.shape[0],10]
noise = tf.random_normal(shape=noise_shape)
out = tf.concat(axis=1, values=[x, noise])
```

But in tensorflow, [x.shape[0],10] doesn't work. Can anyone please light up me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.shape(x)[0]` instead of numpy `x.shape[0]`

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution definitely works. I changed my code in this way. And later I found if I change x.shape[0] to tf.shape(x)[0], it will also work.

Comment: @MingzhangMichaelYin since the solution worked, kindly *accept it* (answers take up valuable time for respondents)